# SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql

First, I know what this error means, but I don't understand why it's appearing. I use this query to update data (it is select generated by framework).

```
UPDATE `achievement` SET `name`='OKer', `description`='sadsad',`IdAchievement`='2' WHERE (`IdAchievement`, '2')
```

I have these records in my database:

**IdAchievement |  name |               description |  IdGame**
1 |              Super achievement|  description |  1
2 |              OK|                 sadsad |      1
5 |              dsfs|                 |            1

IdAchievement is a primary key, IdGame is a foreign key to the Game table.

Can you help me please? I really do not understand it...

Comment: Remove the () around the WHERE statement.

Comment: Hmmm I do not understand, because this generates me Nette framework... :/ Maybe bug in framework or somethink...

Comment: WHERE `IdAchievement` = '2'. Try it and let me know what the result is :)

Comment: It works this way, Ok i am writing to official Nette forum

Comment: I created an answer so you can check this as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to the following:

```
UPDATE `achievement` SET `name`='OKer', `description`='sadsad',`IdAchievement`='2' WHERE `IdAchievement` = '2'
```